# Keep number of rows i Python dataframe based on two column values in one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have the dataframe as shown in the table below:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 124 | 1 |
| 7 | nan | 1 |
| 7 | nan | 1 |
| 8 | nan | 1 |
| 8 | nan | 1 |
| 8 | nan | 1 |
| 9 | 124 | 1 |
| 9 | nan | 1 |
| 9 | nan | 1 |
| 7 | 124 | 2 |
| 7 | nan | 2 |
| 7 | nan | 2 |

I need to keep the rows where Column A is "7" and "9" since Column B contains "124". I don't need all the rows with "8" in i Column A, since "124" is not present in Column B in these rows.

The dataframe should end up with all the instances where the value in Column A matches with "124" in Column B + the rest of the rows where values in Column A are identical with the value in Column A which matches "124" in Column B:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 124 | 1 |
| 7 | nan | 1 |
| 7 | nan | 1 |
| 9 | 124 | 1 |
| 9 | nan | 1 |
| 9 | nan | 1 |
| 7 | 124 | 2 |
| 7 | nan | 2 |
| 7 | nan | 2 |

I have tried to filter the dataframe but can only manage to filter the single rows where Column B is 124 and not the following rows where Column A is identical.

EDIT: I have added Column C to show that not all "7" in Column A is the same, and have to be seperated by Column C.

Answer (score 0):

To get the "124" and the subsequent rows per group, you can use a mask with [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) and boolean indexing:

```
out = df[df['Column B'].eq(124).groupby(df['Column A']).cummax()]
```

If you want all rows of the group:

```
out = df[df['Column B'].eq(124).groupby(df['Column A']).transform('any')]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I get the following error message when executing your code:

"None of [Float64Index([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, nan, nan, nan, nan,\n              ...\n              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, nan, nan, nan],\n             dtype='float64', length=29539)] are in the [columns]"

I have also edited the question by adding Column C. Do you know how to solve that?